# Panning/Dragging of nodes restricts the Viewport

Tags: d3.js

I have implemented panning zooming and dragging in d3 force layout code. They are working fine. However,I noticed one issue with panning/zooming whenever I pan or zoom, the nodes do not expand to complete viewport.

You may get more clarity with the screenshots attached.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pria_3/70qy8ps6/19/    Refer to this code.Try to drag analytics to the corner of the viewport.It gets restricted somewhat before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to change the `cx` and `cy` attributes of `circle` since it is already within the node `group`. Just need to `transform` the node `group` elements. Also note that position of `links` should be updated after `nodes` since position of `links` is calculated from node positions.

Try replacing your `tick` function as shown below.

```
function tick(d) {
    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        var radius = d.children ? 22 : isNaN(parseInt(d.name)) ? 16 : 10;
        d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(w - radius, d.x));
        d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(sh - radius, d.y));
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });
}
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70qy8ps6/29/)

Comment: Thanks Glisha that helps but it hides my layout when i drag it outside the viewport..I tried using  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492   but that gives me trouble with panning and zooming.When i pan/zoom my viewport tends to shift(due to which the main problem i mentioned occurs)..Any idea to restrict the layout with in the viewport (restricting the panning/zooming to the viewport also)

Comment: Hi Priya, I have updated the answer and fiddle. Try now. Hope it helps.

Comment: it restricts the node to go out thanks,,:) but the main problem happens when you pan the background and then try to drag it gets expanded to limited point not to the corner.You can replicate the issue in the fiddle you attached.